# Pegar tags dentro de tags no BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Tenho a seguinte situação:

```
<a href="https://g1.globo.com">Globo</a>
<h3 class="b">
  <a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a>
</h3>
```

Usando o BeautifulSoup, como eu faço para pegar somente o href e o texto da tag 'a' que tá dentro do 'h3'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta buscar a tag `h3` e depois buscar o elemento `a`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """<a href="https://g1.globo.com">Globo</a>
<h3 class="b">
  <a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a>
</h3>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

div = soup.find('h3', class_='b')
a = div.find('a')
print a['href']
print a.text
```

Answer (score 3):

A forma mais fácil é buscar dentro do elemento `h3` a tag `a`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

code = '''<a href="https://g1.globo.com">Globo</a>
<h3 class="b">
    <a href="https://www.google.com">
        Google
    </a>
</h3>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(code)

tag_a = soup.h3.a  

print(tag_a.text)
print(tag_a['href'])
```

Também é possível buscar todas tags com `soup.h3.findAll('a')`, o retorno será uma lista com todas tags buscada.